# Masonry -- items stack on top of each other -- Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, masonry

First time I'm using **Masonry.js**, I try to display my items in a simple grid but all items are just in `position: absolute` so they stack on each other.

I try to add a `margin: 0 auto` on the gutter selector as advice on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46713799/masonry-vanilla-js-stacks-elements-on-top-of-each-other-in-chrome-and-edge) but it won't help.

Here is a fiddle, am I doing something wrong?

```js
let grid = document.querySelector('.main__content'),
  msnry = new Masonry(grid, {
    itemSelector: '.item',
    columnWidth: '.item--sizer',
    percentPosition: true,
    gutter: '.item--gutter',
  });
```

```css
.item {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid darken(#eee, 5%);
  width: calc(50% - 2rem);
  &--sizer {
    width: calc(50% - 2rem);
  }
  &--gutter {
    width: 2rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main__content">
  <div class="item">This is an item 1</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 2</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 3</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 4</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 5</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 6</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 7</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 8</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 9</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 10</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 11</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 12</div>
</div>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
```

Thank you in advance.

*AW*

---

**EDIT**

Regarding Sabuja's answer, I fix the problem as you can see in the following *jsFiddle*.

```js
let grid = document.querySelector('.main__content'),
    msnry = new Masonry(grid, {
      itemSelector: '.item',
      columnWidth: '.item--sizer',
      percentPosition: true
    });
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {box-sizing:  border-box !important;}

.item {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 50%;
  
  &--sizer {
    width: 50%;
  }
  
  &--is-invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main__content">
  <div class="item">This is an item 1</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 2</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 3 with fake news : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut hic et amet, autem provident ab magnam cumque nihil dolorum incidunt fugiat placeat iusto libero sapiente accusantium mollitia velit, harum minima.</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 4</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 5</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 6</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 7</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 3 with fake news : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut hic et amet, autem provident ab magnam cumque nihil dolorum incidunt fugiat placeat iusto libero sapiente accusantium mollitia velit, harum minima.</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 9</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 10</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 11</div>
  <div class="item">This is an item 12</div>
  
  <div class="item item--is-invisible item--sizer"></div>
  <div class="item item--is-invisible item--gutter"></div>
</div>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script can't find required classes in DOM ("item--sizer" and 'item--gutter'). JS can't take it from CSS file.

columnWidth can't find "item--sizer" class in DOM. Add this class to the element you need.
Remove line gutter: '.item--gutter' or add this element to DOM.

Comment: OBVIOUSLY.
I feel dumb right now, but yeah, that was indeed the issue. Pure logic...
Thanks a lot Sabuja!

Answer (score -1):

Add Css class in style

```
    .list-block {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        height: 55px;
    }
```

Html code

```
    <div class="main__content">
        <div class="item-block">
            <div class="item">This is an item 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-block">
            <div class="item">This is an item 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-block">
            <div class="item">This is an item 3</div>
        </div>  
        <div class="item-block">
            <div class="item">This is an item 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-block">
            <div class="item">This is an item 5</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-block">
            <div class="item">This is an item 6</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-block">
            <div class="item">This is an item 7</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-block">
            <div class="item">This is an item 8</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-block">
            <div class="item">This is an item 9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-block">
            <div class="item">This is an item 10</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-block">
            <div class="item">This is an item 11</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-block">
            <div class="item">This is an item 12</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where is .list-block used?